# Игнорирование jstl тегов

Tags: jstl, html

Пытаюсь контролировать отображение столбцов в зависимости от значения переменной section. Но if'ы просто игнорятся и столбцы отображаются всегда. (Чет криво вставляется тут код)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th class="head"></th>
        <th class="head">Task</th>
        <c:if test="${section != 'TODAY' || section != 'TOMORROW'}">
        <th class="head" style="display:none;">Date</th>
    </c:if>
    <th class="head">File</th>
   </tr>
   <c:forEach var="task" items="${task}">
   <tr>
        <td class="check"><INPUT TYPE=checkbox NAME="box"                                            value="${task.idTask}"></td>
        <td class="task"><c:out value="${task.discription}" /></td>
                                                                                         <c:if test="${section != 'TODAY' || section != 'TOMORROW'}">
<td class="date"> <c:out value="${task.date}"/> </td>
</c:if>
<td class="file"><INPUT TYPE=file NAME="file"></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
<c:choose><c:when test="${section != 'FIXED' || section != 'RECYCLE_BIN'}">
<tr>
<td class="check"><input type=hidden></td>
<td class="task"><input type=text NAME="taskDiscription"                                                value="" placeholder="Discription" style="width: 100%;"></td>
                                            <c:if test="${section != 'TODAY' || section != 'TOMORROW'}">
<td class="date"> <input type="date" name="date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"> </td>                                        </c:if>
<td class="file"><INPUT TYPE=file NAME="file"></td>
</tr>
</c:when></c:choose>
</table>
```

Comment: @fars, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Answer (score 1):

Переменная передаётся со значением, которое возможно? Может оно левое или вообще пусто.

P. S. Форматируй правильно код, читать невозможно, это сделать можно, например, [тут](http://jsbeautifier.org).

**Обновление**

Может, обработчик глючит? Обычно в таких случаях нужно аппроксимировать код - сделать один простейший if и посмотреть, что будет. Если всё хорошо, то потихоньку добавлять конструкции до тех пор, пока код работать перестанет - это и будет ошибка. Разумеется, если где-то в логах найдёшь ошибку - это будет чудесно, но if'ы обычно туда не кидают, смекаешь?

Comment: Переменная точно имеет значение. Значение вида TODAY, TOMORROW, SOMEDAY, FIXED, RECYCLE_BIN. В общем сделал проверку наоборот:D Не с оператором !=, а оператором ==. Еще пробовал проверку с оператором 'ne', но тоже пропускало. Короче странно все это.

Comment: Может обработчик глючит?  
Обычно в таких случаях нужно аппроксимировать код - сделать один простейший if и посмотреть что будет.  
Если всё хорошо, то потихоньку добавлять конструкции до тех пор, пока код работать перестанет - это и будет ошибка.  
Разумеется, если где-то в логах найдёшь ошибку - это будет чудесно, но if'ы обычно туда не кидают, смекаешь?